# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Kreait

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, xampp

I just created php web server and connected it to firebase. when I tried authentication, Sign up works just fine. but the problem is in Sign in. it keeps getting this error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Auth::signInWithEmailAndPassword() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/firebase_series/authActions.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/firebase_series/authActions.php on line 24**

here my authentication code:

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");


if(isset($_POST['signup']))
{

    $email = $_POST['emailSignup'];
    $pass = $_POST['passSignup'];

    $auth = $firebase->getAuth();
    $user = $auth->createUserWithEmailAndPassword($email,$pass);
    header("Location:index.php");
}

else
{

    $email = $_POST['emailSignin'];
    $pass = $_POST['passSignin'];

    $auth = $firebase->getAuth();
    $user = $auth->getUserWithEmailAndPassword($email,$pass);
    if($user)
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = true;
        header("Location:home.php");
    }


}

?>
```

and here's my database connection code:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;
use Kreait\Firebase\ServiceAccount;
use Kreait\Firebase\Auth;

// This assumes that you have placed the Firebase credentials in the same directory
// as this PHP file.
$serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');
$apiKey = 'AIzaSyCHULFKW6Kl7FXZc3ZUTYL8fq0f90-kAJ0';

$firebase = (new Factory)
    ->withServiceAccount($serviceAccount, $apiKey)
    // The following line is optional if the project id in your credentials file
    // is identical to the subdomain of your Firebase project. If you need it,
    // make sure to replace the URL with the URL of your project.
    ->withDatabaseUri('https://phpserver-f35e3.firebaseio.com/')
    ->create();

$database = $firebase->getDatabase();


?>
```

Comment: This won't fix your code, but you are using `if($user)` twice. You need to remove one of those.

Comment: yes it is just a typo.

Comment: How are you initializing $firebase variable in the first snippet?

Comment: in index.php
```
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCHULFKW6Kl7FXZc3ZUTYL8fq0f90-kAJ0",
    authDomain: "phpserver-f35e3.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://phpserver-f35e3.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "phpserver-f35e3",
    storageBucket: "phpserver-f35e3.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "265595795371",
    appId: "1:265595795371:web:de597a395dbb8e0bf7c4ee",
    measurementId: "G-JSX6B59K2S"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

Comment: `$email` and `$pass` are not set in that `else` branch

Comment: its just a typo. I already have it in my code

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of the SDK ([kreait/firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php)) you're using :)

Your error says

```
Call to undefined method Kreait\Firebase\Auth::signInWithEmailAndPassword()
```

but I don't actually see this method called in your code. A method called `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` doesn't exist as well, and you're using methods to initialize the SDK that have been deprecated for quite some time now - please make sure to be on the latest release of the SDK (4.40 at the time of this comment).

Once you have, you will have access to the `Auth::verifyPassword($email, $password)` method.

Your code could then look like this:

```php
<?php
// includes/db.php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

$factory = (new Factory())->withServiceAccount(__DIR__.'/google-service-account.json');

$auth = $factory->createAuth();
// no closing "?>"
```

```php
<?php
include("includes/db.php");

// Have a look at https://www.php.net/filter_input to filter user input

if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $email = $_POST['emailSignup'];
    $pass = $_POST['passSignup'];

    $user = $auth->createUserWithEmailAndPassword($email,$pass);

    header("Location:index.php");
    exit;
}

$email = $_POST['emailSignin'];
$pass = $_POST['passSignin'];

if ($email && $pass && $user = $auth->verifyPassword($email, $pass)) {
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['firebase_user_id'] = $user->id;

    header("Location:home.php");
    exit;
}

echo "Authentication failed";
```

If you have further questions concerning the SDK, I'd like to invite you the [Discord community dedicated to the SDK](https://discord.gg/nbgVfty).